# How do you use LetsEncrypt onHostRule with the Consul Catalog backend for LetsEncrypt?

Tags: lets-encrypt, consul, catalog, traefik

I was able to get onDomain working, but someone in the Slack channel stated that onDomain is deprecated for Traefik, though there is no mention of deprecation in the Traefik documentation.

[edit]
There is a reference to this deprecation here: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2212

I am using the Consul catalog backend with host rules for my services, being set with tags:

ex:

```
{
    "service": {
        "name": "application-java",
        "tags": ["application-java", "env-SUBDOMAIN", "traefik.tags=loadbalanced", "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:SUBDOMAIN.domain.com"],
        "address": "",
        "port": 8080,
        "enable_tag_override": false,
        "checks": [{
            "http": "http://localhost:8080/api/health",
            "interval": "10s"
        }]
    }
}
```

However, no certificate is generated for SUBDOMAIN.domain.com - requests just use the TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT.

What is the recommended method for getting Traefik to generate certificates for Consul catalog services automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might only work with the frontEndRule option in the main config, rather than with the "traefik.frontend.rule" override tag.

I added this line:

> frontEndRule = "Host:{{getTag \"traefik.subdomain\" .Attributes
>   .ServiceName }}.{{.Domain}}"

and this Consul catalog tag:

> traefik.subdomain=SUBDOMAIN

and I'm getting the Fake certificate from the LE staging server now.